# File size limit exceeded in bash

Tags: shell, awk, sort, cat

I have tried this shell script on a SUSE 10 server, kernel 2.6.16.60, ext3 filesystem.

The script has a line like this:

```
cat file | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' | sort -n > result
```

The file's size is about 3.2G, and I get the following error message: `File size limit exceeded`.

In this shell, `ulimit -f` is unlimited.

After I change script into this:

```
cat file | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' >tmp
sort -n tmp > result
```

the problem is gone.

I don't know why, can anyone help me with an explanation?

Comment: what happens if you get rid of the cat?  awk is quite capable of reading a file without cat's help.  `awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}' file | sort -n > result`.  How much RAM & swap do you have?  64-bit or 32-bit system?

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting), stuff like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48678/73) tends to happen. Closing here

Answer (score 1):

See [duplicate question in serverfault:](https://serverfault.com/questions/429352/file-size-limit-exceeded-in-bash/429369#429369:)

The pipe version needs many more temporary files.
You can inspect this quickly with the *strace* utility.

The pipe version use a quick exploding number of temporary files:

```
for i in {1..200000} ; do echo $i ; done |strace sort -n |& grep -e 'open.*/tmp/'
open("/tmp/sortb9Mhqd", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
open("/tmp/sortqKOVvG", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
open("/tmp/sortb9Mhqd", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/tmp/sortqKOVvG", O_RDONLY)       = 4
```

The file version doesn't use temporary files for the same data set.
For bigger data sets it use extremely less temporary files.

```
for i in {1..200000} ; do echo $i ; done >/tmp/TESTDATA ; strace sort -n /TMP/TESTDATA |& grep -e 'open.*/tmp/'
```

Comment: But how does *more* files relate to "File (singular) *size* exceeded"?

Comment: More temporary files mean also more stress to the partition containing `/tmp`.

Comment: even if i use the sort -T option to specify a big-enough-directory ,the error still happen